# File Permission

Tags: php

> How i can set **owner and group** to
>   file in php , i write
>
> chgrp("dompdf/background_image.html",1122);
>
> but this is not working
>
> it Set **99** instead of **1122**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a [chown function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) available, however you need the permissions to do so, so you probably have to be root.

There is the [change group](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chgrp.php) functio also availbe, this is the one u used.

Examples are available there, you need the appropriate privileges. that is probably your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [chown](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) and [chgrp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chgrp.php).

Answer (score 0):

From [chgrp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chgrp.php):

Only the superuser may change the group of a file arbitrarily; other users may change the group of a file to any group of which that user is a member.

Answer (score 0):

Try shell_exec() http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('chown ownername:groupname file.php');
?>
```